# PropTypes: array of one of the class instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I am trying to give a type to one of my properties 'listOfItems'. I want this property to be an array of either instance of class 'Event' or instance of class 'Venue'. This is how I have implemented it:

```
MyClass.propTypes = {
 ...,
 listOfItems: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.oneOfType([
   PropTypes.instanceOf(Event),
   PropTypes.instanceOf(Venue)
]))
```

}

However, it doesn't seem to be working. I receive this warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `listOfItems[0]` of value `[object Object]` supplied to `MyClass`, expected one of [null,null].

I don't want to use PropTypes.shape to define array elements, as I will get quite an extended list of shape properties. This is what I mean:

```
MyClass.propTypes = {
 ...,
 listOfItems: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
  ... //list of properties
 }))
}
```

Please share your thought **how would you define an array of objects with certain properties** without writing each property of an object.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.element)` or using Shape is a good approach when comes to readability, you can easily understand what are the different types you can expect in that array.

Answer (score 1):

what fixed for me is to change `oneOfType` to `oneOf`, not sure if thats for your case as well.

Answer (score 0):

PropTypes.shape(...) also matches an object with additional properties as long as the specified properties are present.

So, it isn't necessary to write each property when there is an extended list of shape properties.

To validate an array of class 'Event' instances or an array of class 'Venue' instances:

```
MyClass.propTypes = {
 listOfItems: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
  type: PropTypes.oneOf([Event, Venue])
 }))
}
```